# Is there way to hide/show form field in react in other component or js file just with field ID or name?

Tags: reactjs

i'm wonder if there is way to to hide/show element in react something like 2 way binding.
i'am able to do using react hook or state variable onchange of dropdown.like below

```
 const [value, setValue] = useState();
const handleChange=(event)=> {
   setValue(event.target.value) ;
}
```

and rendering element based on value like

```
{value=='OUTWARD_REPORT' && (
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={6}>
              <FormikTextInputField
                name="departureTerminal"
                label="Departure Terminal"
                disabled={disabled}
              />
            </GridItem>
            )}
```

This is working..
But this flag whether element should be rendered or not is coming from API result,
can i make field hide/show based on api result ?  when i iterate result json, it will have all fileds name with flag  to show/hide field, is there a way to do something like [fieldname].hide/show in for loop. I don't want to iterate json in same js where we have form fields,

Comment: Did you try passing the field as a prop to the component and then do something like `prop.fieldName.show ? <GridItem ...> : null`?

Comment: Hi @WatchfulProtector, Thanks for quick response. Sorry! i'm new to react i did not try that.let me try once, could you provide e any link which will help me to achieve this.

Comment: You should check out the docs. It definitely helps a lot. In this case, you need https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 1):

you can try [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) and for your case if you want to check if some datas are provided from the apis then decide to show/hide elements or component you can do something like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
//Request to api and update the state! if there were no data set it to null
}
render(){return ({this.state.yourValue ? <TheComponentToRunIfThereIsData /> : < TheComponentWhenThereIsNoData /> })}
```

Comment: Thank You Amir, But wont it hide complete component? just to know, sorry if i'm wrong.. i  wanted to hide(avoid rendering)  few fields from form. Api result will have array of all fields with visible flag.i need to iterate and set visibility in loop,  Is that possible ? or i will have to maintain state variable for each filed in that case?

Comment: if you setState it will rerender the component which is using the state! so you can show and hide components! you can also check componentShouldUpdate and check the new state should update your component or not